# Buffering specific roads and calculating inhabitant number

Tags: qgis

I wish to calculate the number of inhabitants (population) who live
within settlements less than 500 meters from highways and from local roads and how
many marines are located less than 20 kilometres from settlements with more than 10,000 inhabitants.

I have roads.shp which consists of 6 categories of the roads and I dont know how to include only highways and local roads for my buffer zone, I mean, I dont know how to "explode" roads.shp and delete or hide other road categories and work with just these two I need.

How can I do this? Not just the roads thing but overall problem above.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so you need to not only state the goal, but detail what you've tried, and what problem resulted.

Comment: So you have and road line layer and what else? Point layers of settlements and marinas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a single, focused question. Remember you can always open multiple questions if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do so :

**1) Run the buffer tool only on the highway and local roads transects :**

- Open the attribute table of your road layer and use the "Select by expression" tool and run the following expression "field name of your layer containing the roads type" IN ('highways', 'local roads')
- Run the Buffer tool (check the "selected features only" and the "dissolve result" options before running the tool)

**2) Sum up your target attribute (inhabitants number) that overlaps with the buffer roads:**

- Select the "Join attributes by location (summary)" tool
  (input layer = buffer roads ; join layer = settlement polygons ; choose "intersect" ; field to summary = number of inhabitants ; summaries to calculate = "sum"

You will get a new buffer layer with a new column with the total number of inhabitants living within settlements less than 500 meters from highways and from local roads. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

**Select Highways and Local Roads:**

Load your "roads.shp" file.
Use the "Select by Expression" tool.
For selecting highways, use the expression: "road_category" = 'Autoceste'.
For selecting local roads, use the expression: "road_category" = 'Državne ceste'.

Now, you have only the desired roads selected.

**Creating Buffer Zones:**

With the selected roads layer, go to the "Processing Toolbox" (Ctrl+Alt+T).
Search for and run the "Buffer" tool.
Set the input layer as the selected roads layer.
Choose the buffer distance (e.g., 500 meters).
Check the options "Selected features only" and "Dissolve result."

**Joining Attributes:**

Run the "Join attributes by location (summary)" tool.
Set the buffer layer as the input layer.
Set the target layer as the layer containing population data.
Choose the statistical summary you need (e.g., sum) for population.
This creates a new layer with population data for the buffered zones.
Identifying Marinas near Populated Areas:

**Select settlements with more than 10,000 inhabitants.**
Use the "Select by Expression" tool with an expression like: "population" > 10000.
Select marinas using an expression like: "feature_type" = 'Marina'.
Buffering Marinas:

**Run the "Buffer" tool on the selected marinas layer.**
Use a buffer distance of 20 kilometers.
Check the option "Selected features only."
Selecting Intersected Marinas:

**Run the "Select by Location" tool.**

Set the marina buffer layer as the source layer. Set the settlement    layer with more than 10,000 inhabitants as the reference layer.    Choose the "Intersect" geometric predicate.

**Exporting Selection:**

- Right-click on the selected features in the marina layer.
- Choose  "Export" and save the selected marinas as a new layer.

You can find screenshots on [this blog.](https://qgistutorialsbasic.wordpress.com/2023/04/01/functions-1/)

Comment: This post was flagged as Spam, which I do not see evidence for. However, if you are affiliated with the blog you link to, please disclose that information.